# Gallery not showing photos from SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-gallery, android-photos

We're building some gallery app.

Recently some users complain that they can't see some folders from their sd card (they can't see it on the stock gallery too).
We check with them and see that there is no `.nomedia` file in the folder.
We also check on our phones and sd cards are read perfectly.

Do you have any idea why is that happen or any way to reproduce it?

Comment: If they switch the phone off and on: do the folders appear? Are the folders hidden themselves?

Comment: No, it's persistent in some way- restarting/ reconnect the sd card not solve it. The can see the folders in folder navigator...

Comment: So your app does not find some folders which contain pictures. Are you determining the folders yourself or are you asking mediastore or so?

Comment: I'm using the media store. that's why the android gallery not find those folders too.

Comment: So better look for files yourself ;-).

Comment: That's a solution, but I really want to understand how this kind of situation could be =)

Comment: Indeed. Interesting issue.

Comment: same happening here.. any idea/solution? most of the gallery apps will use media store..

Comment: You should scan the device folder yourself, that's the only solution that we found back then.